# How to select the four specified incontinous lines simutaniously in vim command?

Tags: vim

Here is my html file which i want to format it.
[image]

The desired format is as following.

[image]

I write command in vim as :

```
：29,30,35,43s/^/ /g
```

It can't take desired effect,how to fix my command?
How to select the four specified incontinous lines simutaniously in vim command?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

But you can do:

```
:29,30s/^/ /|35&|43&
```

See `:help range`, `:help :&` and `:help :bar`.

Comment: |                       To screen column [count] in the current line.
                        |exclusive| motion.  Ceci n'est pas une pipe.

Comment: It is the output of :help bar on my vim.

Comment: It's not `:help bar`, it's `:help :bar`.

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une pipe. What does  Ceci n'est pas une mean here?maybe it is not English vocabulary .Is it an adjective to docerat pipe here?